# LazyLoading Angular 2 Selectors

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I am building an angular 2 app. For one page I have this accordion list.

Accordion1, 
Accordion2…

When clicking on each accordion as expected it opens a div with content. However what I am trying to achieve is to lazy load this content so when clicking on the accordion it redirects me to another url with angular 2 router and lazy loads that module. I have come so far. (e.g that I get redirected and the module lazyloads)

The lazy loaded component has a selector.

This is the template of my accordion. ”risk-report” is the lazy loaded component, 
Of course I get this error:

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'risk-report' is not a known element:
1. If 'risk-report' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Is there any workaround so I can reuse the accordion list and not redeclare it on every url with a new component.

```
<div (click)="toggleOpen($event)" [ngClass]="{'accordion-open': isOpen}" class="reportlist accordion-header">
<i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-minus-circle': isOpen, 'fa-plus-circle': !isOpen}"></i><h3>{{report.reportName}}</h3>
<i class='fa fa-check fa-lg green pull-right' *ngIf="isApproved"></i></div>

<div *ngIf="isOpen" style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray" [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'">

<div style="width: 100%;margin-bottom: 15px" *ngIf="activeReport">
<risk-report (changeReport)="changeReport($event)"></risk-report>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit: So I managed to solve this my self. Just changed riskreport to

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Create a module for `risk-report`, export the component through this new module and load it in your app.module.

Comment: RiskReport already has its own module, and I am loading it with the routers loadChildren. But I still get the error that risk report is not not a known element.

Comment: PLease, provide a plunker or your relevant code to us. Provide the router config, the module lazy-loaded and the component that is trying to use the `risk-report` component.